# Stuck while installing ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to istall ffmpeg on cPanel but I get stuck on this line

svn checkout svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg

I'm following tutorial from http://www.serverhostingsecrets.com/tutorials/cpanel-ffmpeg-howto/

Can someone please help me out here.

Comment: Do you have subversion installed? What's the error you get when you try?

Comment: provide at least OS / error message information ... whe are out of crystal balls today, sorry :(

Comment: I dont think I have subversion installed. How can I install it? Also I am running CentOS 64-bit.When I run that line it just gets stuck there. And after a while spits out timeout error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the [latest release](http://www.ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.6.1.tar.bz2), extract it (tar -xvjpf ffmpeg-0.6.1.tar.bz2), and continue with the tutorial. That should get you around the SVN requirement.

Comment: or better grab the binary somewhere ! there is no need for packages with multimedia - package updates tend to break things by my experience, so get binary from some working system of yours and copy it there. The Ubuntu 10.10 is the first usable ffmpeg I saw in the distros in the long time...